# Stereo triangulation of points

Tags: stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I need to reconstruct 3d position of a tennis ball by using a stereo camera.
I am detecting the ball center positons in the rectified images and pass them to the cv::triangulatePoints(P1, P2, points1, points2, points_out). For the P matrices I use the ones obtained from the camera_info of both cameras.
The reconstructed 3d position is not correct - it moves a lot when the camera is rotated or moved. It looks ok only when the ball is close to the center of the images.
I use the same code for a simulated stereo camera which has no distortion and it works properly so the error is somewhere in the projectiom matrices or detected center coordinates for the real images.
I have compared the matrices in the camera_info when using the simulation and the real camera and they seem ok (the baseline is correct and the rotations also).

There is one thing I have noticed when comparing the images before and after rectification - the image is cropped and resized to the full frame dimensions (done automatically by ROS).

**Is it** properly reflected in the matrices of the camera_info message?

If not, I suppose I have to modify the detected ball center to get the position before the crop/resize?

Can I get the image without the crop/resize? How to do it?

Maybe there is some other problem?

Best,
Patryk

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/179712/stereo-triangulation-of-points/) by [zbuffer](https://answers.ros.org/users/19235/zbuffer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-06-30**:
Have you checked if there is a difference between the camera_info message of the rectified image and the original one? This would at least tell you, whether they are adapted at all.

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-10-13**:
Have you taken a look at the arToolkit package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually there are both topics image_raw and image_rectified

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0